# Хранение разных версий проекта с VCS

Tags: svn, контроль-версий, visual-studio

Требуется хранить разные версии проекта и с возможностью отката при необходимости.
В этих системах контроля версий не разбираюсь сильно, но нужно что нибудь понятное и простое. 
Поставил VisualSVN вроде всё понятно и просто, но так и не понял как разные версии проекта хранить.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, нужно нечто вроде веток, Branch?

ИМХО, это уже далеко не простая вещь, по крайней мере в их реализации)

[Документация](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/using/)

Comment: Не совсем ветки.
Просто хранить разные версии к примеру отдельно 0.5, отдельно 0.6 и т.д. Кстати мне это надо для Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN это всего лишь надстройка над TortoiseSVN.
TortoiseSVN это клиент для SVN способный создать свой SVN репозиторий на диске и работать с ним (без инслалляции специального серверного софта), разумеется с настоящим SVN Сервером он тоже работает. Если под разными версиями понимаются разные ветки проекта то в VisualSVN есть возможности разветвления проекта (т.е. положили проект и сразу создали несколько его веток, каждая из которых, с этого момента, живёт самостоятельно). Если под версиями понимается последовательные релизы одного и того же проекта то в SVN так же имеется возможность фиксировать определённое состояние проекта с возможностью отката до этого состояния. Как это делается технически смотрите доку, тут всего не опишешь. Но я рекомендую Вам смотреть или в сторону Team Server (родной продукт Microsoft - наследник Visual SourceSafe) или же в сторону Git. SVN слегка устаревшая технология. Хотя зависит конечно от Ваших задач.

Comment: > тут всего не опишешь

зато вы написали кучу ложной информации.

Comment: На основании чего, вы, кстати, решили, что `Subversion` — *"слегка устаревшая технология"?*

Comment: сейчас многие перебираются с проектами на git по причине и тут уже место для целой статьи надо резервировать а в 2х словах Git, в отличии от SVN, — распределенная система. Нет центра как в SVN. У каждого разработчика будет своя копия репозиторяи со всеми комитами. Лично мне не хватает в SVN встроенного документатора как в Team Server и распределённости как у Git. Заметьте, я в конце написал в зависимости от задач. Маленькому коллективу сидящему вместе SVN хватит вполне. Проблемы начинаются когда коллектив разрастается и сидит по всему миру. Теперь поясните в чем состоит ложная информация?

Comment: Возможно устаревшая следует заменить на менее удобная, хотя устаревшая, на мой взгляд, подходит тоже. А вообще это уже холивар. Набрите в гугле "чем git лучьше svn" и получите достаточно информации.
п.с. Сам я основные проекты держу под SVN, но это уже определяется спецификой нашего коллектива. Свои личные на GitHub.

Comment: вам, видимо не приходилось работать с репозиториями в тысяч 5 коммитов и "по всему миру". что над чем надстройка - это вообще за гранью. то, что хостят на гитхабе **в основном** проектики на трех-четырех контрибуторов максимум, чаще на одного, с таким же успехом это могла бы быть и svn и любая другая cvs или dcvs.  
Тем временем, ТС спрашивал про `tags`, это понятие есть в любой системе, и конкретно в VisualSVN тоже как ни странно. Странно, что вы про это не сказали, раз на столько опытны в том, что там и откуда.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, по-моему для студии в качестве Source Control лучше использовать Team Foundation Server.